# What FAA legal interpretation clarifies that glider sight-seeing operations do not need a drug testing program?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, glider

I came across this once, and despite searching with Bing and Google cannot find it again. As memory serves, the FAA counsel wrote a letter finding that glider sight-seeing operations do not need approved drug testing programs.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: To save some research time, can you specify what reg the "approved" drug testing programs would be (have been under). Are you referring to Part 135?

Comment: @RTO Good question, but alas I don't know. It was something I read in passing a while back, and I was thinking to send it to a friend who is getting his Part 135 for turboprop charter flights.

Comment: Go to FAA Interpretations, input FAR Part 91.147, and read the "Fields" and "Ragland" interpretations.

Comment: @RTO, Thank you, I didn't know about the FAA Interpretations Search site (https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations). The Fields interpretation was the one I was looking for, esp. re the conclusion that 91.147 does not apply, and therefore there is no need for a LOA or drug testing program. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer so I can give it the nod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the cited FAA Regulations, and pertinent excerpts from the "Field" memorandum/interpretation linked below, it appears that glider sight-seeing operations do not need a drug testing program.

---

[14 CFR Part 120](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-120#p-120.1(a)) - DRUG AND ALCOHOL TESTING PROGRAM

Specifically, 120.1 - Applicability:

states that "This part applies to the following persons:

> (a) All air carriers and operators certificated under [part 119 of this chapter](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-119)  authorized to conduct operations under [part 121](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-121) or [part 135 of this chapter](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-135), all air traffic control facilities not operated by the FAA or by or under contract to the U.S. military; and all operators as defined in [14 CFR 91.147](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-91.147) .

[This FAA Memorandum/Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/faa_migrate/interps/2013/Fields-AEA-200_2013_Legal_Interpretation.pdf) - Subject: Interpretation on Regulation of Sight seeing Rides in Gliders - states, in pertinent parts:

> [...]
>
> Likewise, § 91.147 states that it applies to air tours conducted in
> airplanes and helicopters; it therefore **does not apply to air tours conducted in gliders.** See §
> 91.147(a).

> [...]

> Although glider sightseeing rides are not explicitly excepted from part 119, it is our opinion that
> such operations would not need to be conducted under the authority of a part 119 certificate.
> **First, a glider operation could not be conducted under part 121 or part 125 rules, which apply to
> airplanes, or part 135 rules, which apply to airplanes and rotorcraft.** See§§ 119.21-.25. Next, as
> discussed above, the final rule implementing the part 136 air tour rules and the§ 91.147 rule
> affirmatively state that glider sightseeing operations are not covered by the rule thereby
> indicating the FAA' s intent to not include these operations in the part 119 construct. See 72 Fed.
> Reg. at 6885 (stating the rule "does not apply to gliders (powered or unpowered)"). Therefore,
> the FAA would not require an operator that conducts air tours for compensation or hire in gliders
> to hold a part 119 certificate.
>
> Accordingly, an air tour conducted for compensation or hire in a **glider** may be conducted under
> the part 91 operating rules. **It need not comply with the§ 91.147 commercial air tour rules** or the
> part 136 air tour rules. The operator need not hold a part 119 certificate.

*(emphasis is mine)*